# PDF of $(AB)^C$ where $A, B, C \sim U[0,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, moment-generating-functions

> Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be i.i.d uniform random variables on $(0,1)$.
>
> What is the distribution of $(AB)^C$?

What is a good way to go about answering a question like this?

Trying to find the CDF of this distribution and then differentiating to find the PDF doesn't seem to be a particularly nice way to go about this problem.

Instead I have been trying to use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Multiple_variables) change of variables method ([example here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Example:_Quotient_distribution)). In particular:

Let $X = A$, $Y = B$, $Z = (AB)^C$.

(So the inverse transformation is $A = X$, $B = Y$, $C = \frac{\log(Z)}{\log(XY)}$.)

Then, the joint probability distribution of $X$, $Y$, $Z$ is given by:

\begin{align}
f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) & = f_{A,B,C}(a(x),b(y),z(x,y,z))\cdot|\frac{\partial (a,b,c)}{\partial (x,y,z)}| \\
& = |\frac{\partial (a,b,c)}{\partial (x,y,z)}| \\
& = \frac{-1}{z \cdot \log(xy)} \\
\end{align}

In order to find the distribution of $Z$, I would now need to integrate this w.r.t x and y over $[0,\frac{z}{y}]\times[0,1]$:

$$f_Z(z) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac{z}{y}} \frac{-1}{z \cdot \log(xy)} \,dx  \,dy \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (\text{for} \, z \in (0,1))$$

*This is not easy* (i.e. I don't know how to do this - maybe I am missing a trick as it is a (improper) definite integral?).

**The issue seems to be: either I am going about this question in the wrong way, or, I am using the wrong change of variables.** Indeed, since finding the distribution of Z using the change of variables method only involves integrating the Jacobian, using a different, more clever set of new variables may lead to a much nicer integral - I just have not been able to find such a set of variables.

*Any help would be much appreciated.*

---

**Edit:** In light of the comment below that the distribution of $(AB)^C$ is just $U[0,1$, it seems that a good way to go forward is to consider the MGF. (This did not originally seem like a particularly good option as I had guessed that the distribution would be somewhat esoteric, rather than a ‘known’ one.)

---

**Note:** Wolfram Alpha [says](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%201%2Flog%28xy%29%20dx%20dy%20x%3D0..1%20y%3D0..1) that the integral of $\frac{-1}{\log(xy)}$ over $[0,1]^2$, for example is 1 - am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: There's no easy solution for this problem. One way or the other, you will get involved with either $li(x)$, the logarithmic integral function, or $Ei(x)$ , the exponential integral function.

Comment: @Raskolnikov You are probably right in regards to my current method. Perhaps I’m trying to solve this the wrong way - is it possible that the distribution works out to be some ‘known’ distribution? In this case, perhaps I could try to find the m.g.f and compare it with the m.g.fs of common distributions? Admittedly I’m not too hopeful...

Comment: This has a surprisingly simple answer that $(AB)^C \sim U[0,1]$ again. I haven't seen any simple solution with easy trick, and earnest computation of triple integral indeed leads to the answer.

Comment: @SangchulLee In light of your comment, my idea in my previous comment  of comparing m.g.f.s seems a lot more hopeful - I shall give it a go! Thank you!

Comment: For some intuition about this result: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/493017/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing *a priori* that the distribution of $(AB)^C$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ suggests that this problem can be attacked by utilizing moment generating functions:

Let $X = \log(Y), \, \text{  where } Y \sim U[0,1]$.

The MGF of $X$ is given by
\begin{align}
M_X(t) & = \mathbb{E}(e^{tX}) \\
& = \mathbb{E}(e^{t\log(Y)}) \\
& = \mathbb{E}(Y^t) \\
& = \frac{1}{t + 1} \\
\end{align}

Now consider $Z = \log((AB)^C) = C\log(AB)$

The MGF of $Z$ is given by
\begin{align}
M_Z(t) & = \mathbb{E}(e^{tZ}) \\
& = \mathbb{E}(e^{t\,C\log(AB)}) \\
& = \mathbb{E}(\, \mathbb{E}((AB)^{\,tC} \, | \, C \,)) \\
& = \mathbb{E}(\,( \mathbb{E}(A^{\,tC} \, | \, C \,))^2) \,\text{ as } A, B \text{ are i.i.d.}\\
& = \mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{(tC + 1)^2}) \\
& = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(tc + 1)^2} \, dc \\
& = \frac{1}{t + 1}
\end{align}

Hence, $X$ and $Z$ have the same distribution, so $e^X$ and $e^Z$ have the same distribution.

In other words, $(AB)^C \sim U[0,1]$.

Had we not known beforehand that the distribution was going to be uniform, we would have had to notice that $\frac{1}{t + 1} = \mathbb{E}(Y^t)$ (which is not too hard to see). However, had the final distribution not been as nice, then this method would have failed; it seems that the method mentioned in the question, or the method used in Sangchul Lee's answer is more reliable in the general case.

Perhaps a more intuitive idea of how we may have spotted/deduced more simply that this has a relatively simple distribution is given in the top answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261783/distribution-of-xyz-if-x-y-z-is-i-i-d-uniform-on-0-1); I highly rate this answer, as it shows how some good experience can make the path to an answer more natural.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a brutal computation: let $w \in (0, 1)$ and set $W = (AB)^C$. Then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(W \leq w)
&= \int\limits_{\substack{(xy)^z \leq w \\ x,y,z\in[0,1]}} dxdydz
 = \int\limits_{\substack{z(u+v) \geq -\log w \\ u\geq 0, v\geq 0, z\in[0,1]}} e^{-(u+v)} \, dudvdz
\end{align*}

where we utilized the substitution $(x,y) = (e^{-u},e^{-v})$. Further substitution with $(t, \lambda) = (u+v, \,\frac{u}{u+v})$ gives

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(W \leq w)
&= \int\limits_{\substack{zt \geq -\log w \\ t\geq 0, z\in[0,1]}} t e^{-t} \, dtdz
 = \int_{0}^{\infty} t e^{-t} \max\left\{0, 1+\frac{\log w}{t} \right\} \, dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \max\left\{0, t+\log w \right\} \, dt \\
&= \int_{\log w}^{\infty} e^{-s+\log w} \max\left\{0, s \right\} \, ds \qquad (s = t+\log w) \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} w e^{-s} \, ds
 = w.
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice job, didn't think you'd avoid the logarithmic integral.

Comment: Could you just clarify what is happening when you make the substitution $t = x + y$ ? Where does the extra $t$ come from in the following line (in front of the $e^{-t}$ )?... I am not too familiar with substitutions transforming a double integral to a single integral, but I assume it is equivalent to $(x,t) \rightarrow (x, x+y)$, which doesn’t explain the extra $t$.

Comment: @JohnDon, I admit that I was a bit hasty when explaining that substitution. It is more like a polar coordinate change. For this specific case, you can utilize the substitution $(t, \lambda) = (u+v, \frac{u}{u+v})$ and notice that $$ \left| \frac{\partial(t,\lambda)}{\partial(u,v)} \right| = \frac{1}{t}. $$ This substitution gives $dudv = tdtd\lambda$ and maps the region $u \geq 0, v \geq 0, z(u+v)\geq-\log w$ to the region $t \geq 0, zt \geq -\log w, 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$. Then the integration over $\lambda$ simply yields $1$ without affecting other factors, only leaving integral over $t$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Ahh... That explains it. I will have to keep such a substituion in mind for the future. How did you come about that substitution - did you somehow work it out, or did you just know it was a good substitution from experience? Thanks anyway! (Also, might it be worth pasting that explanation into your answer?)